# Difference in processor performance in base 13" Mid 2020 and upgraded 13" Mid 2020 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

Is there any difference in the efficiency of the processor between the two MacBook Pro:

1. **Mid 2019, 13" MacBook Pro upgraded to 2,8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7**
2. **Mid 2020, 13" MacBook Pro (Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports, base model)**

[image]

I am fully satisfied with the 2019 version I have now. But is it at least the same, as the base model Mid 2020 13"?

Would [public geekbench](https://www.geekbench.com/) results for above macs be an effective comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can trust geekbnech for quite neutral results for CPU capabilities for macs in the last 5 years.

That being said, I’m never in a case where the CPU is what is actually holding me back. The things that chew CPU are never things I’m waiting on and I go have dinner or let it run to complete. The things that make me happy are good software, efficient software, not having memory leaks and fast storage.

I get that on a 2015 MacBook with a 1.2 GHz CPU and NVMe SSD with 8 GB of RAM. All of the machines you specify are overkill for what I need. The question is what benchmark and code do you run - can you profile it on your current mac and then decide if the investment in a new mac is worth the money in time you save.

No benchmark will tell you that.

Comment: I am looking forward to if i even get a new MacBook Pro or go all iPad and then get the 2020 Mac Mini - those look amazing to me for the few things I need and can’t load into a hosted mac. We’ll see on Xcode though - my existing mac does build slowly so having the code checked in and CI builds on a MacPro 2013 or Mac Mini 2020 will be in my future for sure. I just don’t want to drag my main build system with me anymore if I can avoid that.